# How to draw a chart in runtime using Active Reports?

Tags: .net, vb.net, activereports

I need to draw a chart in runtime and save it as a jpg file using **Active Reports**.

I already managed to create a `SectionReport` and add a `ChartControl` to it:

```
Dim chartControl As New ChartControl()

Dim series As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Chart.Series
series.Type = Chart.ChartType.Bar3D

Dim objs As New List(Of Teste)()
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE1", .Valor = 15})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE2", .Valor = 22})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE3", .Valor = 10})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE4", .Valor = 36})

Dim chartArea As New ChartArea()
chartControl.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)

chartControl.DataSource = ConvertToDataTable(objs)
chartControl.Series.Add(series)
chartControl.Series(0).ValueMembersY = "Nome"
chartControl.Series(0).ValueMemberX = "Valor"

Dim rpt As New SectionReport()
rpt.DataSource = ConvertToDataTable(objs)

rpt.Sections.InsertPageHF()
rpt.Sections(0).BackColor = Color.LightGray

rpt.Sections.Insert(1, New Detail())
rpt.Sections(1).BackColor = Color.PeachPuff
rpt.Sections(1).Height = 1.5

rpt.Sections(0).Controls.Add(chartControl)

rpt.Run()

Export(rpt.Document, "C:\Testes\")
```

The `Export` method works and generates the jpg, the problem is that the chart doesn't appear in the image; in it's place, there's a message that says "Failed to draw the chart.". I've tested the Export method with a chart created on the Active Reports designer, and it worked perfectly.

That's the generated jpg file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with the following code. I really don't know why, but it worked.

```
Dim objs As New List(Of Teste)()
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE1", .Valor = 15})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE2", .Valor = 22})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE3", .Valor = 10})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE4", .Valor = 36})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE5", .Valor = 36})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE6", .Valor = 36})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE7", .Valor = 36})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE8", .Valor = 36})
objs.Add(New Teste With {.Nome = "TESTE9", .Valor = 36})

Dim chartArea As New ChartArea(True)
Dim series As New Series()

For Each obj As Teste In objs
    Dim pt As New DataPoint()
    pt.XValue = obj.Nome
    pt.YValues = New DoubleArray(New Double() {obj.Valor})
    series.Points.Add(pt)
Next
series.ChartArea = chartArea
series.Type = ChartType.Bar2D
series.ColorPalette = ColorPalette.Iceberg

Dim chartControl As New ChartControl()
chartControl.DataSource = ConvertToDataTable(objs)
chartControl.Series.Add(series)
chartControl.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)

Dim rpt As New SectionReport()

rpt.Sections.InsertPageHF()
rpt.Sections.Insert(1, New Detail())
rpt.PageSettings.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
chartControl.Width = CSng(rpt.PageSettings.PaperWidth / 1.35)
chartControl.Height = CSng(rpt.PageSettings.PaperHeight / 5)

rpt.Sections(1).Controls.Add(chartControl)

rpt.Run()

Export(rpt.Document, "C:\Testes\")
```